# Flutter - Firebase, Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm having an issue when I try to input some information from text fields to Firebase. I'm getting this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
```

I tried to update my dependencies but they are all up to date. Did someone have the same problem and solved it?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding **firebase_core_platform_interface** dependency without a version to your app's *pubspec.yaml* file:

Like this:

```
dependencies:
  ........
  ........  
  firebase_core_platform_interface:
```

And then do a `pub get` after `flutter clean` from `CLI/Terminal`.

If it still doesn't work rename the file `pubspec.lock` to `pubspec_ORG.lock`and then:

Run all of these from `CLI/Terminal`:

`flutter pub outdated`

`flutter upgrade outdated_package`

`flutter clean`

`flutter pub get`

Hope this helps.

PS: Renaming the file `pubspec.lock` to `pubspec_ORG.lock will help you revert to the original` pubspec.lock` file in case you need to.